# I don't know how to push and store multiple prototype objects using array.push()

Tags: javascript

So i have a prototype function

```
function Weekday(name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}
```

i have to create a protoype object and store it in a different array using that function above

```
function mostPopularDays(week) {
    var week = new Weekday('Monday',5);
    week.push('Tuesday', 3);
    return week;
}
```

but then i have to create and push more objects to the same array using array.push(). But the problem is i don't know how.

I'm new to javascript and programming in general, so any explanation is valuable.

Comment: Hi, perhaps you could use an array `weeks = []; weeks.push(weekday); console.log(weeks)`

Comment: `week` is not an array, it’s an instance of `Weekday`. Do you want it to be an array?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, that's what i wanted to do, but didn't know how. Now i do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`week` is not an array, you can't push into it. You need a different variable to hold the array of objects.

```
function mostPopularDays() {
    var day1 = new Weekday('Monday',5);
    var day2 = new Weekday('Tuesday', 10);
    var all_days = []
    all_days.push(day1);
    all_days.push(day2);
    return all_days;
}
```

Comment: what would they say at my working place? "Why don't you use camelCase for your variables but for your function name?" :D and `week` is not used at all :)